# How do I show that all of the chains in T's chain basis have the same length?

Tags: linear-algebra, nilpotence

Let $T: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ be a nilpotent operator, $h \in \mathbb N$ s.t. $KerT^h=ImT^h$.

How do I show that all of the chains in T's chain basis have the same length?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean $T:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$? Your question doesn't make much sense as written

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You're right! edited

Comment: Also, it is not necessarily true that the basis chains have the same length.

Comment: This is what I need to show because $KerT^h = ImT^h$. @Omnomnomnom Can you give your counter-example please?

Comment: For instance:
$$
\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}
$$
One chain has length $1$, the other has length $2$.

Comment: Is there something that we know about $h$?

Comment: Oh, in my example there is no $h$ with $\ker T^h = Im \ T^h$

Comment: that there exist $h \in \mathbb N s.t. KerT^h=ImT^h$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can prove the claim as follows.  Note that the span of any chain is an invariant subspace (in particular, a generalized eigenspace) of $T$.  Suppose that $U_1, \dots, U_k$ are the subspaces spanned by each of the different chains.

Let $T|_U$ denote the restriction of $T$ to $U$.  Note that if $\operatorname{Im}(T^h) = \ker(T^h)$, then we must have $\operatorname{Im}(T^h) \cap U_j = \ker(T^h) \cap U_j$ for each $j$, which is to say that 
$$
\operatorname{Im}(T|_{U_j}^h) = \ker(T|_{U_j}^h) \quad j = 1,\dots,k
$$
However, because each $U_j$ is the span of a chain, we have $\dim \ker T|_{U_j}^h = h$.  By the rank-nullity theorem, we have
$$
\dim(U_j) - h = h \implies \dim(U_j) = 2h
$$
Thus, each $U_j$ has dimension $2h$.  That is, the **length** of each chain must be $2h$.  So, each chain has the same length, as desired.